# SQL multiple Where Statements not working

Tags: sql

Is it a syntax error?

```
SELECT MEAL_TIMEOFDAY,MEAL_NAME FROM APP.MEAL

WHERE MEAL_TYPE         = ('Cardio')
WHERE MEAL_TIMEOFDAY    = ('Breakfast')
```

I need to only get Cardio Meals that are breakfast.

Comment: Kill the parentheses, since they're not needed, remove the extra `WHERE`, and connect the conditions with `AND` or `OR`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one condition in your SQL [`WHERE` clause](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) you have to use [logical operators](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp), *e.g.*:

```
SELECT MEAL_TIMEOFDAY
    , MEAL_NAME
FROM APP.MEAL
WHERE MEAL_TYPE = 'Cardio'
    AND MEAL_TIMEOFDAY = 'Breakfast'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following and the above will not work:

```
SELECT MEAL_TIMEOFDAY,MEAL_NAME FROM APP.MEAL -- This will work for the condition you provided
WHERE MEAL_TYPE = 'Cardio' AND MEAL_TIMEOFDAY = 'Breakfast'
```

Or simply:

```
SELECT MEAL_TIMEOFDAY,MEAL_NAME FROM APP.MEAL -- This is a sample with OR
WHERE MEAL_TYPE = 'Cardio' OR MEAL_TIMEOFDAY = 'Breakfast'
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL queries are structured as follows:

```
SELECT [columns] FROM [table name]
  WHERE [condition one]
     AND [condition 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

replace the second where with "OR"

Comment: AND would be the more likely interpretation of 2 where's and this doesn't address parenthesis either.  plus OP states "Cardio Meals that are breakfast" which means and